# Как правильно указать путь для publicPath для webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack4, webpack-dev-server

Есть такая сборка...

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


const webpackConf = {
    entry: './frontend/app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './production'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'production/'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 80,
        overlay: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './index.html', // Комментарий №1 
            template: './frontend/main_pages/tamplate_en.html',
            title: "Index"
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};


module.exports = () => {
    return webpackConf;
};
```

Тут все работает, но как только я меняю путь для создания `index.html` ***(Смотреть Комментарий №1 выше в коде)***, `publicPath: 'production/'` не видит `index.html`

Что только не пробовал

> publicPath: 'production/main-pages/'

> publicPath: 'main-pages/'

Вот что получаю...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственное, что придумал, так это менять путь для создания `index.html`

При `production` задать один путь а при `development` другой...

Верное ли будет такое решение или есть какой-нибудь путь проще решить данную проблему?

Дополнения...

В эту папку собирается сборка ***production***

> path: path.resolve(__dirname, './production'),

Если у меня плагин

***new HtmlWebpackPlugin*** создает `index.html` в корне папки ***production***,
то все работает, а мне надо что бы ***new HtmlWebpackPlugin*** создавал `index.html` папки ***production/main-pages/***

Так вот, когда `index.html` не в корне папки ***production***, а в папке ***production/main-pages/*** devServer не видит `index.html`, не срабатывает  `publicPath: 'production/'

Comment: что-то я ничего не понял, что на что ты меняешь и где что смотришь?

Comment: добавь минимальный пример структуры и конфига которые работают и которые не работаеют

Comment: @Grundy, минутку

Comment: не понял какая результирующая структура должна получиться

Comment: @Grundy, глянь дополнения к вопросу

Comment: посмотри [`publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverpublicpath-) у девсервера, у меня получилось только чтобы по `localhost/production/main-pages` открывалось. Возможно надо в другую сторону подумать, типа [contentBase](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercontentbase)

Comment: @Grundy, и так и этак...  Пробовал... Ладно утро вечера мудренее... Поколдую утром

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю за участие...

Comment: @Grundy, разобрался, еще раз благодарю... С твоей подачи...)  Меня несколько смутило описание, скорее перевод описания `contentBase` там про статические файлы, а о другом подумал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы `devServer` понимал где находиться главный `index.html`

`publicPath: '/'` должен указывать корень проекта

в `devServer:` надо добавить

`contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'production')`  который указывает на папку сборки

`openPage: 'main-pages/en/index.html'` который явно указывает какой файл запускать

`openPage:` можно указать массив нескольких фалов

`openPage: ['main-pages/en/index.html', 'main-pages/ru/index.html', 'main-pages/ge/index.html']`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {
    CleanWebpackPlugin
} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


const webpackConf = {
    entry: './frontend/app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './production'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 80,
        overlay: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'production'),
        openPage: 'main-pages/en/index.html'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './main-pages/en/index.html',
            template: './frontend/main_pages/tamplate_en.html',
            title: "Index EN"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './main-pages/ru/index.html',
            template: './frontend/main_pages/tamplate_ru.html',
            title: "Index RU"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './main-pages/ge/index.html',
            template: './frontend/main_pages/tamplate_ge.html',
            title: "Index GE"
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};



module.exports = () => {
    return webpackConf;
};
```